# Chrome browser set interval alert statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have this below piece of code to check the session. The checksession is called every 15 seconds.

This code works fine in IE browser but in Chrome, the alert statements never pop-ups and it redirects directly to the given url...

```
setInterval(checksession, 15000)

function checksession() {
    alert('check session')
    $.ajax({
        aynsc: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'CheckSession',
        success: validateresult,
        data: {
            antiCSRF: '{{acsrf}}',
            session_id: '{{session_id}}'
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Session check failed')
        }
    })
    return false;
}

function validateresult(result) {
    if (result == "N") {
        valid_flag = "N"
        alert("Your session has been timed-out based upon Security Policy. Please click OK to be redirected to the login page to start a new session.");
        window.location.assign('./')
    } else {
        valid_flag = "Y";
        return valid_flag
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the error. (simplified jsfiddle)[http://jsfiddle.net/847x2/]

Comment: Correct [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/847x2/)

Comment: @Arthur.sw..Thanks...I think my problem is my Ajax call that screws up...What changes needs to be done to my Ajax all to make it work..Not sure why it works without any problem in my IE

Comment: Side note: `aynsc: false` should be `async: false`. But why even use Ajax if it isn't asynchronous?

Comment: Either way it does not work...